# FormSubmit doesn't update value without refresh page

Tags: angular, typescript, api, ionic-framework

I'm facing to an issue concerning my form submit.
When I submit my form, the values are updated well but not reactive. I have to refresh the page to see the modification.
I'm using Ionic v4 / Angular 8 / API.

```
  onFormSubmit(){
        this.isLoadingResults = true;
        this.invoiceService.updateInvoiceItems(this.data[0]['id'], this.form.value)
          .subscribe((res:any) => {
            const id = res.id;
            this.isLoadingResults = false;
            this.router.navigate(['/invoice-details', this.data[0]['invoice_id']]).then(() => {window.location.reload()});
          }, (err: any) => {
            console.log(err);
            this.isLoadingResults = false
          }
         );
      }
```

For my test, I'm using the property

> window.location.reload()

but it's not what I want to do for a clean code.

Thank you

Comment: It's unclear from your code as to why your "invoice-details" page isn't showing updated values. You're going to have to provide more code. What exactly is not updating? What do you mean by "updated well but not reactive"?

Comment: I mean, when I'm updating my values through the form, the value are changed in my API but I have to refresh the page to check it on the page

Comment: Show the code for the "invoice-details" page. How are you fetching the data that is to be displayed in that view?

Comment: Sure I'll share the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some researches, I did it !

I used events property in my submit function to redirect to a function to display data after editing.

Answer (score 0):

use BehaviourSubject to dynamically update data without refreshing page.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class invoiceService {

    public myData: BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]> = new BehaviorSubject<SomeType[]>([]);

    constructor(private storage: Storage) {  }


    updateInvoiceItems(data): Observable<any>  {

        this.myData.next(data);
        return this.myData.asObservable();

    }

}
```

```
export class InvoiceComponent implements OnInit {
  updatedData : Observable<boolean>;

  constructor( public authService : AuthService ) {
    this.updatedData = invoiceService.updateInvoiceItems(formData);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

invoice-service.ts

```
  getInvoice(id:number): Observable<Invoice>{
    return this.http.get<Invoice>(`${environment.apiUrl}api/invoices/${id}`)
}

getInvoiceItems(invoiceId:number): Observable<InvoiceItem[]> {
    return this.http.get<InvoiceItem[]>(`${environment.apiUrl}api/invoiceitems`)
    .pipe(
        map((invoiceitems : InvoiceItem[]) => invoiceitems.filter(inv => inv.invoice_id == invoiceId))
    );
}

 updateInvoiceItems(id:any, invoiceitems:any):Observable<any>{
        return this.http.patch(`${environment.apiUrl}api/invoiceitems/${id}`, invoiceitems, this.httpOptions)
          .pipe(
            tap(_ => console.log(`updated invoice id=${id}`)))
    }
```

invoice-details.ts

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

    this.invoiceService.getInvoice(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.item = result;
      //console.log(this.item)
    })
    this.invoiceService.getInvoiceItems(this.id).subscribe(result => {
      this.data = result;
     //console.log(this.data)
    })
  }
```